# How to generate code coverage in Laravel for folders other that the 'app'

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug, laravel-artisan

I have a project on the **Laravel v9.15.0** and **PHP v8.1** and I have changed the `phpunit.xml` file to generate code coverage for the `modules` folder in my project, which sits side by side with the default `app` folder, but the generated HTML report is just empty.

- I have no problem with the `app` folder with my current Xdebug setup.
- I use `php artisan test --coverage-html reports` to generate the results the in `reports` folder.

This is the contents of my `phpunit.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="">./modules/*/tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="">./modules/*/tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <!-- <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/> -->
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is an issue or not but try replacing `./modules/*/tests/Unit` and `./modules/*/tests/Feature` with `./modules/**/tests/Unit` and `./modules/**/tests/Feature` (yes, double `**` instead of 1)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
 </include>
```

to

```
<include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
</include>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `processUncoveredFiles="true"`. I used to keep it when using homestead but if using sail, you'd rather remove it.